# How to send a POST request with BODY post nested json using swifty json swift3?

Tags: ios, json, post, swift3, swifty-json

I'm trying to make a post request with a body in swift3 using SwiftyJSON
[image: my json body looks like :]

I check lots of post Json post nested objects in swift using SwiftyJSON , How do I access a nested JSON value using  SwiftyJSON? none of them helped for this situation.

Comment: Are you looking for JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json) and then request.httpMethod = "POST" ?

Comment: are you want to create request body like above?

Comment: yes kuldeep how can i post my data in post API ?

Comment: @chris Chen yes how can i post my data in post API !!

Comment: please share above request in string.

Comment: https://medium.com/swift-programming/http-in-swift-693b3a7bf086 Please google it

Comment: but how to share in the string, the type of request is the same i really need code how can i solve it?? - Kuldeep

Comment: kuldeep - now u can see my edited code hope so is it ok ...!!